# Валидность html5

Tags: html, html5

Подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы при валидации веб-страницы результат был без всяких замечаний со стороны валидатора. А именно чтоб результат был (Passed), а не (Passed, 2 warning(s)).

Вот мой код, что нужно сюда добавить чтобы результат был без всяких замечаний.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML XMLNS="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <HEAD>
        <META CONTENT="text/html; charset=utf-8" HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type">
        <LINK HREF="css/vidvig_menu.css" REL="stylesheet" TYPE="text/css">
        <TITLE>выдвигающиеся меню</TITLE>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
        <DIV ID="menu"></DIV>
        <!-- #menu -->
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

На счёт тега META (пробывал вписывать по новому meta charset="utf-8", результат тот же).

Comment: This document was successfully checked as HTML5!Все норма

Comment: @Роман Соколов, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Comment: XMLNS="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" можешь вообще убрать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Желательно закрыть теги meta и link

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<LINK REL="stylesheet" TYPE="text/css" HREF="css/vidvig_menu.css" />
```

Comment: [Неправда](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/syntax.html#syntax-start-tag). HTML5 не XHTML, и не требует закрытия тегов. Более того, он интерпретирует `/>` как `>`, и например, `<div />` поймёт не как `<div></div>`, а как `<div>`.

Answer (score 2):

Желательно:

1. Должны иметь вложеный конечный тэг
2. Названия тэгов и атрибутов должны быть написаны строчными буквами
3. В тэги <html> лучше использовать lang="ru" для ясности

После этого, документ пройдёт проверку и валидатор на W3C максимум выдаст 1 ошибку о том, что используется html5. Если вы смените доктайп на xhtml, тогда ошибок не появится вообще.

*Для html5 могу посоветовать пользоваться этим [html5.validator.nu](http://html5.validator.nu) валидатором.*

Answer (score 1):

[Валидатор W3C](http://validator.w3.org) выдаёт по этому коду два предупреждения. Прочитаем:

1. общее предупреждение относительно того, что проверка синтаксиса HTML5 считается у них "экспериментальной", и не стоит на неё полагаться на 100%;
2. кодировку он только угадывает как UTF-8, т.к. веб-сервер ничего не сообщил о кодировке, ведь я просто скопипэйстил этот код в форму.

А документ, поздравляю, проверку прошёл, валидный.

Answer (score 0):

lang="ru" стоит добавить тегу HTML